# Decomposition of $L^p$ function into $L^2$ tail part and $L^1$ body part

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with rational $1 \le p \le2$. I'm primary
interested in methods to generalize the Fourier transforamtion
from $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $p$ as above without
deal with distribution theory at all. By Plancharel-theorem there is a
natural way to extend Fourier transformation to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
by exploit density of $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in
$L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a limit argument.

For general $1 \le p \le2$ I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_other_Lp) an interesting approach but nowhere literature references where
following approach is explaned in detail and where I can find an
existence & uniqueness proof of the claim:

> For $1 \le p \le2$ the functions in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be
> decomposed into  a fat tail part in $L^2$ plus a fat body part in $L^1$.

Is it  done in most naive way that every $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has
decomposition $f=g+h$ with $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n), h \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
Why it should exist and up to what is such decomposition unique? Can the decompostion be constructed always explicitely of is it just an existence statement?

does anyone know books where these questions are answered?

Comment: Maybe a trick like $f =  f 1_{ \abs{f} > 1} +  f 1_{ \abs{f} \leq 1}$ could work.

Comment: Clearly the decomposition is only unique up to addition of functions in $L^1 \cap L^2$.  Seems to me that Frederik’s construction works straightforwardly as $x^1 \le x^p$ for $x \ge 1$ and $x^2 \le x^p$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.